# Adding 'manager' from seperate trusted domain

Tags: active-directory

I have 2 domains that trust each other.

I need to change a single user's manager attribute to a user from the other domain.

The selection window for this only allows me to select the domain that contains the user, is there another way to do this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. While a trust allows for the access of resources from one domain to the other (and vice versa) I don't believe it allows for the sharing of object attributes.

Comment: Seems you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. The manager attribute has to exist in the domain of the account that you're setting it on.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this is not possible. If you have user in forest A and another user in forest B then you cannot set B as manager of A (or vice-versa).

If you synchronize both forests to Azure AD then it remain not possible if your on-prem forests remain the source master. This was confirmed by Microsoft.